# Serializable and extensible API implementing the Command Design Pattern

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns, template, networking

I am currently trying to implement an extensible way to create commands that can be sent to some type of executor. In my case, there would be two of them (server and client). As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162484/calling-a-derived-class-method-from-the-parent-class-same-method), I had a hard time developping my idea, but it finally came through something usable, but a bit complex in my opinion.

I am thus looking for advice, and maybe ideas that could make this code better!

There is a working example at the last file for anyone wondering*.

## protocol.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef PROTOCOL_HPP_
#define PROTOCOL_HPP_

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#define MAX_COMMAND_BODY_LENGTH 512



namespace nw {



class command_base {

  public:
    using id = uint8_t;
    using buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>;

    static constexpr size_t header_length{sizeof(id)};
    static constexpr size_t max_body_length{MAX_COMMAND_BODY_LENGTH};

  protected:
    // We don't want to instanciate this class
    ~command_base() {}

};



template<class Executor>
class command: public command_base {

  public:

    using executor_t = Executor;
    using pointer = std::unique_ptr<command>;

    // This one has to be specialized later (when creating the executors)
    enum class command_t: id;

    command() = delete;
    explicit command(id);

    static pointer unserialize(buffer);
    buffer const serialize() const;

    virtual void execute(executor_t&) = 0;


  protected:

    id id_;

    buffer const serialize_header() const;

    // implementations will need to define this, 
    // depending on the member variables of the 
    // subclass.
    virtual buffer const serialize_body() const = 0;


  private:

    static pointer do_make_command(
      id const, buffer::const_iterator, buffer::const_iterator
    );

};



} // namespace nw


#include "protocol.ipp"

#endif // PROTOCOL_HPP_
```

## protocol.ipp

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring> // memcpy


namespace nw {



template<class T>
command<T>::command(id id): id_(id) {}



template<class T>
command<T>::pointer command<T>::unserialize(buffer buffer) {

    auto it{buffer.cbegin()};

    if (std::distance(it, buffer.cend()) > header_length + max_body_length) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "command::unserialize: buffer is too long."
        );
    }

    command::id id;
    std::copy(it, it + sizeof(id), &id);
    it += sizeof(id);


    return std::move(do_make_command(id, it, buffer.cend()));

}



template<class T>
command_base::buffer const command<T>::serialize() const {

    buffer header{serialize_header()};
    buffer body{serialize_body()};

    if (body.size() > max_body_length) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("command::serialize: buffer is too long.");
    }

    // Join the two buffers into one
    buffer res;

    res.resize(header.size() + body.size());

    auto it{res.begin()};

    std::copy(header.cbegin(), header.cend(), it);
    it += header.size();
    std::copy(body.cbegin(), body.cend(), it);

    return res;

}



template<class T>
command_base::buffer const command<T>::serialize_header() const {

    buffer buff(header_length);
    auto it{buff.begin()};

    std::memcpy(&*it, &id_, sizeof(id_));
    it += sizeof(id_);

    // Normally not necessary, but better safe than sorry
    buff.shrink_to_fit();

    return buff;

}



template<class T>
command<T>::pointer command<T>::do_make_command(
    id const                id,
    buffer::const_iterator  beg,
    buffer::const_iterator  end
) {

    switch(static_cast<command_t>(id)) {

        default: throw std::invalid_argument(
            "command::unserialize: Unknown server command ID."
        );
    }

}



} // namespace nw
```

## command_example.cpp

```cpp
#include "protocol.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



namespace nw {


// Create an executor that can handle the commandsthat are gonna be implemented
// (could be a server or a client, for example)
class MyExecutor {

  public:
    // This one doesn't do much....
    void print(std::string msg) {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }

};


// We need to specify what commands are gonna be usable from that executor
// We thus specialize the command template with the enum
template<>
enum class command<MyExecutor>::command_t: command_base::id {MessageCommand};



// We define a simple command that prints a message through the executor
class MessageCommand: public command<MyExecutor> {
  public:

    // First, we need to construct the command, we assign its ID,
    // then do stuff with the buffer (here it only contains a string,
    // that we store directly in a variable. It is EXTREMELY important
    // that we have at least this constructor with this signature,
    // since it's the one used by unserialize
    MessageCommand(buffer::const_iterator b, buffer::const_iterator e):
        command(static_cast<id>(command_t::MessageCommand)),
        msg(b, e)
    {}

    // Feel free to make other constructors
    MessageCommand(std::string s):
        command(static_cast<id>(command_t::MessageCommand)),
        msg(s)
    {}

    // Simple execute function
    virtual void execute(MyExecutor& e) {
        e.print(msg);
    }

  protected:

    // finally, we need to create the body serializing method.
    // This one is easy, since it can directly store the only
    // variable it holds
    virtual buffer const serialize_body() const {
        return buffer(msg.cbegin(), msg.cend());
    }


    std::string msg;

};

// This I'm really not sure... How do I define the specialized
// do_make_command method???
// That way seems too verbose. I guess I will only have to
// do that twice (Server/Client) so it doesn't really matter

// added later: I could probably just directly make do_make_command virtual,
// and implement it completely.Some repeated code but whatever I guess.
template<>
command<MyExecutor>::pointer command<MyExecutor>::do_make_command(
    id const                id,
    buffer::const_iterator  beg,
    buffer::const_iterator  end
) {

    // This is always the same thing, we just add new cases
    // when adding new commands... This is the part I like the least.
    // Could maybe make a Macro to add cases??? But Macros are baaad :(
    switch(static_cast<command_t>(id)) {

        case command_t::MessageCommand: return pointer(
            new MessageCommand(beg, end)
        );

        default: throw std::invalid_argument(
            "command::unserialize: Unknown MyExecutor command ID: "
                + std::to_string(id)
        );
    }

}



} // namespace nw

// Now it's super easy to use!
int main() {
    using namespace nw;

    // Instanciate executor
    MyExecutor exec;

    // Create some commands
    std::string my_message{"Hello!"};
    MessageCommand my_command(my_message);

    std::cout << "Executing from the manually constructed command:\n";
    my_command.execute(exec);


    // Can serialize/unserialize to be sent through some stream/socket,
    // for example.
    std::cout << "\nExecuting from serialized then unserialized command:\n";
    command<MyExecutor>::pointer c{
        command<MyExecutor>::unserialize(
            my_command.serialize()
        )
    };


    c->execute(exec);


    return 0;
}
```

Basically, having to specialize the enum template seems a bit verbose...
Could I instead have a second template argument which is an enum when defining command?

```cpp
template<class Executor, class Enum>
class command {
    // ...
};
```

Is there anything else that I could do to improve this design?

NB: This is the start of my first real *more ambitious* project in C++, so if there is any cue about my style/things I do wrong, I am open to criticism

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get how your code will work ... every template instantiation of command<T> defines its own enum class command_t, then the 'id_' in each command<T> will always be 0, right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You can see in the third code block how it works. The commands implemented from `command` call `command`'s constructor with the good id from the enum (which btw I moved to the Executor class instead of specializing the template, made more sense)

Comment: could you create another command class, print out the value of its 'id_' and include it in your example code? That'll make it easier to understand the way how id works.

Comment: I mean the id_ of my command here would be `command<MyExecutor>::command_t::MessageCommand` (or `MyExecutor::command_t::MessgeCommand>` in my new version) which would probably be 0 here

Comment: but if you add another command command<MyOtherExecutor>, as well as MyOtherCommand class, the id_ of this command would be MyOtherExecutor::command_t::MyOtherCommand, which would still be 0 (since it's defined as a separate enum). Is this what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, this is okay because when intercepting a command, you specify what executor is expected (`command<EXECUTOR>::unserialize(...)` so it doesn't matter

Comment: OK. I *kind of* understand the point of id now -- presumably you'll have more enum values under command<MyExecutor>::command_t: ```enum class command<MyExecutor>::command_t: command_base::id {MessageCommand, AnotherMessageCommand, AThirdMessageCommand, etc};```. Given your usage of passing commands between client/server, your design is overly engineered. Unless you give some description of your other ambitious use cases, you don't really need those templates, base class.

Comment: I will definetely need something like this, there will be a lot of different server instances with different APIs and I need something extensible and reusable. But my question was more about the code here and what it does than what it's gonna be used for :p

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> using id = uint8_t;
> using buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>;
>
> static constexpr size_t header_length{sizeof(id)};
> static constexpr size_t max_body_length{MAX_COMMAND_BODY_LENGTH};
> ```

Misspelt `std::uint8_t` and `std::size_t` here - that's a lurking portability bug (you're getting away with this because your current compiler is exercising its option to declare global-namespace copies of standard identifiers, but will fail on compilers that don't do that).

`command_base` is intended to be a base class, so its destructor should be **`virtual`**.

Given that `buffer` is a `std::vector` and `it` is `buffer.cbegin()`, we can replace `std::distance(it, buffer.cend())` with a simple `buffer.size()`.

Comment: Thank you! What I don't understand is the size_t you're refering too. Should I cast max_command_body?

Comment: No cast is needed; just change `size_t` to the correct `std::size_t`.